# Двумерный массив, удаления строк

Tags: java

Есть задача, в которой нужно удалить строки из многомерного массива, чтобы сумма цифр, которые остались в массиве, приближались максимально в процентном соотношении от общей суммы массива к циферке, заданной пользователем в консоли.
Алгоритм какой-никакой накидал... Но не могу понять почему цикл у меня бесконечный? И во-вторых, как можно удалить строку?(преобразовывать строку в лист и удалять? Или весь массив? (я только начал учиться, так что не ругайте)), а то я только меняю на нолики строку, которую хотелось бы удалить.

```
    public class Task15 {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // Matrix percent
    Scanner percent = new Scanner(System.in);
    int percentNedded = percent.nextInt();
    int percentLeft = 100;
    int[][] matrixRandom = Util.createRandomMatrix(10, 10, 100);

    for (int i = 0; i < matrixRandom.length; ++i) {
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(matrixRandom[i]));
    }
    int indexOfMax = Util.rowIndexOfMaxNumber(matrixRandom);// index of max number
    int matrixSum = Util.matrixSumm(matrixRandom);
    System.out.println(matrixSum + " " + percentNedded);
    int row1 = 0;
    int row2 = matrixRandom.length - 1;
    while (true) {
        int pecentDifferent = percentLeft - percentNedded;
        int row1summ = Util.matrixRowSumm(matrixRandom, row1);// тут сумма строки
        int row2summ = Util.matrixRowSumm(matrixRandom, row2);
        if (row1summ > row2summ && (row1summ < pecentDifferent * matrixSum / 100) && row1 != indexOfMax) {
            for (int i = 0; i < matrixRandom[row1].length; i++) {
                matrixRandom[row1][i] = 0;
            }
            percentLeft -= row1summ / matrixSum * 100;
            row1++;
        } else {
            if (row2summ < pecentDifferent * matrixSum / 100 && row2 != indexOfMax) {
                for (int i = 0; i < matrixRandom[row2].length; i++) {
                    matrixRandom[row2][i] = 0;
                }
                percentLeft -= row2summ / matrixSum * 100;
                row2--;
            } else
                break;


        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < matrixRandom.length; ++i) {
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(matrixRandom[i]));
    }
}
```

}

Comment: скорее всего  percentLeft -= row1summ / matrixSum * 100 == percentLeft 
ну скажем row1summ  = 100
получается 100/matrixSum * 100 = 1/matrixSum = 0,1 скажем. 
http://ideone.com/JsF87w вот тут посмотри результат. интересно получается

Comment: надо row2summ / matrixSum * 100 округлить вверх

Comment: там даже у вас получается 100- (10/100)*100=100-10=100...
то-есть мне не инт обявлять нужно, а другой тип переменной?

Comment: надо BigInteger с округлением вверх

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Скорее всего

```
percentLeft -= row1summ / matrixSum * 100 == percentLeft
```

Скажем `row1summ = 100`, получается `100/matrixSum * 100 = 1/matrixSum = 0,1`. [Тут посмотри результат](http://ideone.com/JsF87w). Интересно получается

```
100- 1/10 = 100
```

Для int надо `row2summ / matrixSum * 100` округлить вверх.